# concat and cast in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, concatenation, hiveql

I have number of records that include couple of columns with leading zeros.  I would like to remove leading zeros and combined 3 columns into one with hyphen.  I am using HIVE.

```
Column1    column2    column3
0123        12342567    001


desired output
123-12342567-1
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove leading zeroes you can use regexp_replace(col, '^0+', ''), then concatenate using concat_ws():

with mytable as (
select
'0123' Column1, '12342567' column2, '001' column3
)

```
select concat_ws('-',
                 regexp_replace(Column1,'^0+',''),
                 regexp_replace(Column2,'^0+',''),
                 regexp_replace(Column3,'^0+','')

                )
  from mytable;
```

Result:

```
123-12342567-1
```

In case some column value is `NULL`, `concat_ws` will skip it along with separator.  For example if column2 is NULL, the result will be `123-1`

If you want to transform `NULL` values to something else, use `NVL(col, 'value if NULL')` function, for example `regexp_replace(NVL(column2, ''),'^0+','')`  will return empty string instead of NULL and concat_ws will return `123--1`